# How to post picture on the wall?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Does anybody sucessfuly post picture to current user's wall? This is not working, if picture argument is existing picture url post is not shown! I'm using latest FB C# SDK 5.0.8 Beta ...

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["name"] = "My App";
args["link"] = @"http://apps.facebook.com/test/";
args["caption"] = "My Caption";
args["description"] = "My Description";
args["picture"] = @"http://www.test.com/test.jpeg";
args["message"] = "My Message";
args["actions"] = "";
FbClient.PostAsync(@"/me/feed", args);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I handled posting a photo to the Facebook User's wall. ImagePath and ImageName were string parameters that I passed into the function that contains this code.

```
    var fbApp = new FacebookApp();
    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);

    if (auth.IsAuthorized())
    {

        //Create a new dictionary of objects, with string keys
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        string strDescription = txtDescription.Text;

        //Add elements to the dictionary
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImagePath) == false)
        {
            //There is an Image to add to the parameters                
            FacebookMediaObject media = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = ImageName,
                ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            };

            byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);
            media.SetValue(img);

            parameters.Add("source", media);
            parameters.Add("message", strDescription);

            try
            {
                dynamic result = fbApp.Api("/me/photos", parameters, HttpMethod.Post);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle error....
                string strErr = ex.Message.ToString();
                lblValidationMsg.Text = strErr;
            }
        }            

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in version 5.0.8. It has been fixed in the current source and will be in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

You can use post in the user wall (**"me/photos"**)

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@".\resources\velas_navidad.gif", @".\")]
    public void Post_to_photos()
    {
        var ImagePath = "velas_navidad.gif";
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(ImagePath));

        var client = new FacebookClient(token);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

        parameters.message = "Picture_Caption";
        parameters.subject = "test 7979";
        parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
              ContentType = "image/gif",
              FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
        }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath));

        dynamic result = client.Post("me/photos", parameters);

        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        client.Delete(result.id);
    }
```