# how to post image from byte[] to users wall

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to post message to user's wall with picture.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
 {
     {"access_token", accessToken},
     {"app_id", appId,
     {"message", message},
     {"link", linktoapp},
 };
 //photo is byte[]
 FacebookMediaObject media = new FacebookMediaObject
  {
      FileName = "Result",
      ContentType = "image/jpeg"
  };
  media.SetValue(photo);
  parameters.Add("media", media);

  var app = new FacebookApp();
  var fbCB = new FacebookAsyncCallback(callback);
  app.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters, fbCB);
```

Post is displayed on wall, but without picture.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500016/how-to-post-picture-on-the-wall .  In this example, the post is targeted at `/me/photos`, whereas you are targeting `me/feed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500016/how-to-post-picture-on-the-wall), you'll want to pass `"/me/photos"` as the first parameter of your `FacebookApp.PostAsync()` call.

Answer (score 2):

post it to `me/photos` instead.

Comment: If you want post to wall in **"me/feed"** with picture (_parameters.picture = "x.png"_) ?  View http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982904/get-access-token-programmatically-in-unit-test-method