# Get Access Token programmatically in Unit Test Method

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

First, I open Facebook Developers page, and I create new App. ( I get AppID, AppSecret values)

I want create  Unit Test method for do **Post to the wall,** and later **delete the post.**
publish_stream, publish_actions

***Manually***, I do this 3 steps

Open url

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.kiquenet.com/&scope=publish_stream,publish_actions

Then, this url opened, and I get the **code value**:

[http://www.kiquenet.com/?code=A....3qhOw#*=*](http://www.kiquenet.com/?code=A....3qhOw#_=_)

And then, open this url and I get the **access token** value:
[https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.kiquenet.com/&scope=publish_stream,publish_actions&client_secret=zzzzz&code=A...3qhOw#*=*](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.kiquenet.com/&scope=publish_stream,publish_actions&client_secret=zzzzz&code=A...3qhOw#_=_)

Finally, I get the access token:

```
  const string token = "C...SNo";
```

My code now is for my unit test is working. Only I need do the delete.

```
using Facebook;
        [TestMethod]
        public void Post_to_the_wall()
        {

            var client = new FacebookClient(token);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
            parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
            parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
            parameters.name = "Article Title";
            parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
            parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
            parameters.actions = new
            {
                name = "View on Zombo",
                link = "http://www.zombo.com",
            };
            parameters.privacy = new
            {
                value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
            };

            dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);

           // TODO: NOW, delete the post ???
        }
```

How can I do programmatically the 3 ***Manually*** steps ?

Comment: why do you guys still use publish_stream, when it´s deprecated since years?

Comment: anyway, you can´t authorize a user manually.

Comment: Which is the publish_stream new value ? All actual values list about it ?

Comment: you only need publish_actions

Comment: I m also looking for a way to do this. all our server side game code is driven by unit tests and I have to test facebook features .. for the moment I put a token manually in the code and have to change it every 2 months..