# Delete Post of Wall Facebook using SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I newbie using Facebook SDK for C#

I have seen this post to wall in unit test.
[Get Access Token programmatically in Unit Test Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982904/get-access-token-programmatically-in-unit-test-method)

Now, I want to delete post in my wall.

```
using Facebook;
        [TestMethod]
        public void Post_to_the_wall()
        {

            var client = new FacebookClient(token);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
            parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
            parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
            parameters.name = "Article Title";
            parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
            parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
            parameters.actions = new
            {
                name = "View on Zombo",
                link = "http://www.zombo.com",
            };
            parameters.privacy = new
            {
                value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
            };

            dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);

           // TODO: NOW, delete the post ???
        }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: i don't think you have permission do do that.

Comment: In my wall, in Facebook, I can delete my post. Why not using Facebook SDK ? not support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
 dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);

 client.Delete(result.id);
```

Post method get Postid (id property), and you can use it for delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post

> An app can delete a post if it published it

Check out the example code on that page. You need a User Token with publish_actions to make a `DELETE` request to `/post-id`.

Comment: How can I get **post-id** value ?

Comment: me/feed posting will return the post id